# Vim's advance word broken in python, how do I fix this?

Tags: python, vim

Vim works fine for all other languages, but word detection seems wonky in python. For example, in the following snippet, with the cursor on the 'h' in shutil, I would expect prssing the w key to advance me to the period, instead I get moved to the "'" in front of export.

```
shutil.copytree(os.path.join('export', 'app'), os.path.join('export', 'pacakge'))
```

Any idea what could cause this? How can I detect the cause? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look to see what the option "iskeyword" is set to.  Chances are the Python syntax file is changing it.  Normally it's set to `@,48-57,_,192-255`.

Comment: Also, use `:verbose set isk?` to find out where it was last changed.

Comment: Thanks! This was it. My isk was being changed unexpectedly.